# Taking type of virtual method within class scope

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Disclaimer: Maybe what I'm trying to do is prohibited by the standard, if so please let me know.

I'm trying to take the type of a virtual method (pointer) with `decltype` within the scope of the class defining the method. This works fine with GCC, but hard crashes Visual Studio 2013:

```
class foo
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    // typedef decltype(&foo::bar) bar_pointer; // crashes VS2013 (error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler)

};
typedef decltype(&foo::bar) bar_pointer; // works fine with VS2013
```

For various reasons I need the type within the class, so I'm trying to work around this crash. Interestingly enough, the following compiles with VS2013:

```
class foo
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    typedef decltype(foo::bar) bar_pointer; // works in VS2013, GCC complains(invalid use of non-static member function)
};
```

Here, the type of `bar_pointer` comes out as `void __thiscall foo::(void)`. Doesn't make much sense to me, I guess this is some erroneous type. Yet I tried to transform this type to a valid method pointer type by passing it to a template specialization which extracts return type and parameter types. But it seem like this weird type doesn't match any specialization I could come up with.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here or can think of a way to workaround this issue?

**UPDATE:**

Seem like this is not directly related to `decltype`, but to unevaluated contexts in general. The following also crashes:

```
class foo
{
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    static const size_t test = sizeof(&foo::bar);
};
```

Comment: "For various reasons I need the type within the class" Can you elaborate? This looks to be an XY problem.

Comment: Maybe you should add address operator `&` in second sample.

Comment: @themagicalyang: It's about a static reflection library in which a meta type describing the methods of a class is definied within the class.

Comment: Just for curiosity (ignore if it would works but I guess the answer): have you tried to use `using` statement instead `typedef` ?

Comment: @Albjenow: You mean decltype(&foo:bar)? Then it is the same as the first sample (which crashes).

Comment: Have tried to replace `bar_pointer` with `typedef void foo::(*bar_pointer)();` to work around `decltype`?

Comment: @Horstling How good is the `decltype` support in VS2013 ?

Comment: @Gonmator: No change when using `using`

Comment: The one with `&` works for me with GCC independent of the place of the `typedef`.

Comment: @Frank: `typedef void (foo::*bar_pointer)();` works, but I need to deduce the type from the method.
@Arunmu: `decltype` support is complete in VS2013 afaik (except for SFINAE issuse), but obviously there are still some bugs

Comment: Related: [VC++ Internal Compiler Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091662/vc-internal-compiler-error)

Comment: How about creating a nullptr and asking for the return value of the function? `decltype( ( ( foo* )nullptr )->bar() )`

Comment: @Trevir: Doesn't work because `foo` is still a incomplete type at this point.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it works fine with GCC/Clang:

```
struct Foo {
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    using baz = decltype(&Foo::bar);
};
```

So it looks like an MSVC++ bug/pecularity (member function pointer type depends on class properties).
One way to work that around is to declare virtual class "interface" ahead:

```
struct IFoo {
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};
struct Foo : public virtual IFoo {
    using baz = decltype(&Foo::bar); // note, it works with Foo member function pointer now
};
```